# Using Nextje App Routing and project structure

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, antd, directquery

I want to start a project with these technologies.
This project is about Learning Management System, and it will be a web application.

- Nextjs, using app directory and new features
- AntDesign
- Tailwind
- GraphQL
- Apolo or ReactQuery for Caching

**So My Questions**

1- Do you have any ideas or commnets?

2- Do I have any challenges with Nextjs App Routing?

3- Is Ant Design integrated with new Nextjs?

4- Will I be able to use server component in Nextjs with AntDesign components?